# 2 instances of fckeditor in firefox11

Tags: php, firefox, fckeditor

In my admin panel I have 2 instances of fckeditor (2.6.4), but in ff11 the second instance isn't visible.
In other browsers (including ff10) don't have this problem.

```
$oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('ps_short_description') ;
$oFCKeditor->Width = '600';
$oFCKeditor->Height = '300';
$oFCKeditor->BrowserPath = SHOP_WWW_PATH.'/upload/fck_files';
$oFCKeditor->Value = "";
$oFCKeditor->Create() ; 

$oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('ps_description') ;
$oFCKeditor->Width = '600';
$oFCKeditor->Height = '500';
$oFCKeditor->BrowserPath = SHOP_WWW_PATH.'/upload/fck_files';
$oFCKeditor->Value = "";
$oFCKeditor->Create() ;
```

HTML code in ff11 and ff9 is the same (Firebug).

How to deal with this problem?

Comment: how do you insert your fckeditor to adminn panel? Through javascript? Give you insertion code here.

Comment: Whats the HTML output look like for each browser ? and please learn to format your code properly ... its not difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, the simplest thing to do may be to wait 11 days until Firefox 12 is released.  This bug is fixed in Firefox 12.